# Could the different versions of the Master talk telepathically to each other?

Tags: doctor-who, clones

In Season 4 of Dr. Who:

> The Master clones his pattern onto 7 billion humans.

Can the different copies of the Master communicate telepathically with each other?

> because in the episode, they have to use radio and television to talk to each other, and the others don't seem as though they know what is happening in the room when the Dr. makes his escape with the Cacti.

Answer (score 4):

There is no solid answer as to whether they are *capable* of doing so. The best example of Time Lord to Time Lord telepathy we see on screen is in The Three Doctors. There, the first three Doctors telepathically link, each saying "contact" and apparently entering a mode of rapid communication as the camera alternates between them. A possibly relevant detail of this scene is that The First Doctor is not physically present: he appears via The TARDIS's "scanner" (a wall mounted television generally used to look outside of The TARDIS in this age when having the doors open to exterior scenery was too expensive). One might argue that he is a long way away, one might argue that the nature of his contact with The TARDIS negates this.

So, we can reasonably argue that instances of The Master are capable of telepathy in this fashion. We might allow that an instance in China could form "contact" with the original instance in England.

Given that, we can see some pitfalls which make more conventional communication preferable. While in "contact", The Doctors were in deep concentration, filtering out direct physical stimuli. The Doctors were in line of sight, there were only three of them, there were clear distinctions between them, and that represented all of the Time Lords they were directly aware of. During the existence of "The Master Race", there were nearly 7 billion, all but identical, instances of The Master. The two instances needing to communicate could not see each other. One wonders if the two instances in question could find each other in the masses of uniformity around each of them. Further, The original Master was in a command and control role, needing to keep abreast of events as they unfolded: the deep concentration of "contact" wouldn't work well with this. Barring that, he could use a local intermediary to perform the "contact", having the intermediary verbally relay the content of the communication to the original. At this point, conventional communication is faster and easier.

Comment: The Doctor(s) spoke telepathically *again* in The Five Doctors.